# Getting the value selected from drop down list into a string variable c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

```
static public String Titl;
```

Now in simple programming language suppose i got a dropdown list on my form. when i debugged i found out that dropdowlist with the id dropdownlist1 when written

```
dropdownlist1.text;
```

contains the value i selected in the dropdown menu. However when i did something like this:

```
titl = dropdownlist1.text;
```

i was not getting the value in the titl variable. Help needed. Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

check this if you want text..then

```
 title=dropdownlist1.selecteditem.text;
```

and if you want value then

```
  title=dropdownlist1.selecteditem.value;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int selectedIndex=dropdownlist1.SelectedIndex;//get index
string selectedText=dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.Text;//get text
string selectedValue=dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.Value;//get value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Title = !string.IsNullorEmpty(dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.Text) ?
 dropdownlist1.SelectedITem.Text : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Titl = dropdownlist1.SelectedValue;
```

Works! Thank You!